# If the eigen values of an orthogonal matrix A are positive, then the determinant of A is 1 why??

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

can anyone say why the above statement is the way it is. Why determinant is 1?

Comment: $A^TA=I$ implies $\det(A)^2=1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Determinant of an orthogonal matrix is either $1$ or $-1.$

Also product of Eigen values of a matrix is equal to the determinant of that matrix.

Now, given that Eigen values of $A$ are positive, so its determinant is $1.$

Comment: If the eigen values of a 3X3 matrix A and the eigen values of its inverse are equal, then the matrix A is a an identity matrix why?

Comment: Nik please explain in more detail I did'nt get you buddy.

Comment: Your question is not correct in the sense that if $A$ happens to be non-identity  $3\times 3 $ involuntary matrix. Then eigen values of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are equal but $A$ is not an identity matrix.